# How should I interpret decimals in guitar tabs?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, guitar-effects, tablature, harmonics

### [image: Harmonics]

I found this in the *Black Clouds & Silver Linings* - Dream Theater Guitar Tab Book. The notation implies a harmonic on the second and third strings, but what do 2.7 and 3.2 mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that this is referring to where you would place your finger to get the desired harmonics.  The harmonic that generates the major third is right before the 4th fret, which would be 3.85.  3.2 would be a harmonic near just beyond the 3rd fret, which should give you a D on the G string.[image: Picture]  This picture outlines the placement of the harmonics and the decimal representation for some of them.  Looking at the harmonic that shows not in parentheses in your example, the image doesn't match decimal-wise but you can see that the note that corresponds is the same.

Comment: The harmonic that generates the (major) third (plus two octaves), namely the 5th harmonic, is right before the _fourth_ fret, 3.85 to be precise. 3.2 is indeed the sixth harmonic (two octaves and a fifth), and 2.7 is the seventh harmonic, which on the B string is close to A6 (but significantly lower than a proper fifth up from the D6 harmonic on the G string).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks!  I had originally written 4th and 3.8/3.9 and somehow convinced myself that I was wrong.  Probably didn't help that I was nowhere near my instrument.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - Does the newly added picture clarify things for you?

Comment: Nice, that's a lot clearer!

Comment: It'd be cool to have a guitar with these positions marked with inlays.

Comment: @luserdroog - Yeah, that could be cool but ultimately they are all over the guitar, so there could be a whole lot of extra markings because of that.  You can see with the harmonics that are slightly behind the 4th fret (not labeled with a decimal even though they should be, as leftaroundabout indicated in his comment) are also the same as those near the 9th fret.  You could play that harmonic in either spot and get the same note.  It ultimately seems more effective to just memorize where about they are.

Comment: True, upon further thought, it'd be more useful to have markings around the pickups and near the bridge for artificial harmonics. I saw a  video with a 30-fret guitar that made artificial harmonics easier.

Comment: That's something I wouldn't mind having if it didn't clog things up too much.  I only really use artificial harmonics on a few songs and the one that's harder to accomplish has it right at the start and since I mostly play bar gigs, I can just get myself in position and test the notes prior to the song actually starting (which I probably wouldn't do on a big stage).